# How to log in as another user at the same time

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin

I have a users table and using spatie/laravel-permission package. I need an admin to be able to log in temporarily as a different user and see the website as that user's point of view. The admin should not be logged out when temporarily logged in as the other user. Is there a way to do something like this in Laravel?

Comment: Unless you have two different session managers for both `admin` and `users`, you can't be logged in as two users at the same time.

Comment: You should "log in" that user, but as an admin you can give yourself permission to view other profiles as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely do that in laravel. To do that you need to install the package

> https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate

And here is Some basic usage of the package

```
//here 10 indicates the user id and you can change this

$otherUser = User::find(10);

Auth::user()->impersonate($other_user);
//now you are logged in as the user id with 10

//to stop impersonating

Auth::user()->leaveImpersonation();

// You're now logged as your original user.
```

And for More usage kindly check the Docs

[Docs(Readme)](https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate#simple-usage)

**If You are Not intrested in Package kindly check the below links:**

https://pineco.de/impersonating-users/

https://mauricius.dev/easily-impersonate-any-user-in-a-laravel-application/

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/impersonating-users

Comment if there is any isues

Comment: I didn't know of this package. You learn something new everyday

Comment: if my answer solves the issuse kindly accept my answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need an ability to work in admin panel and user panel at the same time. When impersonate a user - admin session is down and i get 403. Any idea?

Comment: if you need to log in as admin then you need to logout the user that logged in. Or you must be using the multiple guard. for auth